# Node.JS Autogenerate WSDL Methods with Args

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

A quick background to the scenario:

I recently went from being a web developer to being a Penetration Tester for a different company. Recently I had to do a security audit of a SOAP Web Service and found very few tools out there to give me a hand in doing so. Thus I thought I'd create my own, even if it's only for personal use.

I thought Node.JS would be a quick and easy language to knock up a prototype in, however, having never done SOAP with Node.JS I'm not sure whether I am being blind to something or whether it's more complicated.

My question is, using the node-soap package, how would I auto-generate the methods with associated arguments within my program? https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap

I use the soap.createClient() method to then describe() the WSDL which is fine, but I'm not sure how to then loop over the methods/args from the WSDL. Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Update:
https://github.com/richard-clifford/WSDLFuzzer/blob/master/main.js

The above link is the main file for the fuzzer at the moment. It is supposed to ingest any given WSDL file, test the methods within the WSDL, then fuzz the values. All of which the user should only have to pass the WSDL to the program.

Comment: Look @ this bit https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soaplistenserver-path-services-wsdl---create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services

Comment: Yeah but that's for the server, I want to create a client to test a remote Web Service.

Comment: I'm confused, if you had some code to look at, that would help. I can't figure out why you need `Node.js`. Are you trying to duplicate the service on your own server?

Comment: Added the code in the update

Comment: So you want to create a Client.js (sort of) based on the WSDL spec ? Well, I think your node-soap module is just creating the client server-side. What you could do with nodejs is to use "browserify" and bundle your script to it. Than you could be able to use it within the browser as client.js -> http://browserify.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use your "Main.js" in the browser, therefore the go to way would be to install browserify:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

After that go to your project folder "WSDLFuzzer/main.js" and type

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

At the end go to your .html file and add

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

This should now allow you to use your soap library within the browser. And you use require at different parts of your code, I hope you already installed that packages (colors, soap,...).

More About Browserify here https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook